# How to configure hyphenation by iText7?

Tags: java, itext, itext7, hyphenation

I try to hyphenate a String with the [iText7 hyphenation](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/best-itext-questions-stackoverview/general-questions-about-itext/itext7-how-hyphenate-text).
I used the example Code, but it returns null and not a hyphenated String or Hyphenation Object:

```
Hyphenator h = new Hyphenator("de", "DE", 2, 2);
Hyphenation s = h.hyphenate("Leistungsscheinziffer");
System.out.println(s);//this is null and not "Lei-stungs-schein-zif-fer"
```

My depenedncies from the pom.xml are:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>hyph</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Is there any I forgot to configure?

Thank you for helping me to solve this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `hyph` as a `test` dependency (see `<scope>`). Which means, it is only added when you are running tests. If you want to use `hyph` in non-test environment, make sure the dependency is e.g. `compile` (default is `compile`):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>hyph</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Oh what a embarrassing mistake! Thank you for this quick solution.